# How to trim a string in SQL Server before 2017?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2017, you can use this syntax, but not in earlier versions:

```
SELECT Name = TRIM(Name) FROM dbo.Customer;
```

Comment: TRIM DOES NOT EXIST in version 2016 and older versions.

Answer (score 304, accepted):

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Names)) AS Names FROM Customer
```

Comment: this is the easiest way to do it, just remember to alias your column being returned

Comment: @Miles - I added the alias for completeness.

Comment: I understand that this is the right way to use the trimming of the value.
but can you explain why to use both LTRIM and RTRIM when we could have used just TRIM instead?

Comment: @CodeBuster: SQL Server doesn't have TRIM function defined, even in 2014 version.

Comment: Please note that `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` handle only spaces, you will have to remove other **blank** characters like tab and line feed yourself.

Comment: SQL Server now has TRIM in the 2017 version. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql

Answer (score 67):

To Trim on the right, use:

```
SELECT RTRIM(Names) FROM Customer
```

To Trim on the left, use:

```
SELECT LTRIM(Names) FROM Customer
```

To Trim on the both sides, use:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Names)) FROM Customer
```

Comment: Incidentally, what possible reason could Microsoft have for including an LTRIM and RTRIM function without a TRIM?  It's peculiar.

Comment: Because it is redundant.  You can accomplish the same thing with LTRIM(RTRIM(var)).

Comment: Yes, but that's two function calls.  You could say they are all redundant since TSQL has CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING, but that's an idiotic way to look at it.

Comment: It's not redundant at all.  Not offering a single function called TRIM puts the syntax burden on the user.

Comment: It was probably an oversight, or one of those features that got axed because every feature starts at -100 points (which really just leads to incoherent feature sets instead of prioritized feature sets, IMHO).

Comment: TRIM isn't "redundant" compared to LTRIM(RTRIM()).  It can be used that way but TRIM can actually do so much more with much more than just leading and trailing spaces.  Please see the following MS Documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql#b--removes-specified-characters-from-both-sides-of-string

Answer (score 8):

I assume this is a one-off data scrubbing exercise. Once done, ensure you add database constraints to prevent bad data in the future e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE Customer ADD
   CONSTRAINT customer_names__whitespace
      CHECK (
             Names NOT LIKE ' %'
             AND Names NOT LIKE '% '
             AND Names NOT LIKE '%  %'
            );
```

Also consider disallowing other characters (tab, carriage return, line feed, etc) that may cause problems.

It may also be a good time to split those Names into `family_name`, `first_name`, etc :)

Comment: That's really going to slow down inserts a whole lot, especially because of the leading wild cards.  Those types of checks should be done well before the data gets anywhere near a permanent table and won't do the required job for a staging table.

Comment: @JeffModen: "That's really going to slow down inserts" Me: "I assume this is a one-off data scrubbing exercise" - so we're not in disagreement, it seems.

Comment: @onedaywen - Totally understood but, almost every time I've heard of someone making such an assumption, it somehow makes it's way into production.   :D

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Replace(Replace(Replace(name,'   ',' '),CHAR(13), ' '),char(10), ' ')))
from author
```

Answer (score 3):

Extended version of "REPLACE":

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE("Put in your Field name", ' ',' '))),'''',''), CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(160), '') [CorrValue]
```

Answer (score 1):

in sql server 2008 r2 with ssis expression we have the trim function .

SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) is a component of the Microsoft SQL Server database software that can be used to perform a broad range of data migration tasks.

you can find the complete description on this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139947.aspx

but this function have some limitation in itself  which are also mentioned by msdn on that page.
but this is in  **sql server 2008 r2**

```
TRIM("   New York   ") .The return result is "New York".
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with MS SQL except that it's in a product bundled with the database.

Answer (score 0):

To trim any set of characters from the beginning and end of a string, you can do the following code where @TrimPattern defines the characters to be trimmed. In this example, Space, tab, LF and CR characters are being trimmed:

Declare @Test nvarchar(50) = Concat (' ', char(9), char(13), char(10), ' ', 'TEST', ' ', char(9), char(10), char(13),' ', 'Test', ' ', char(9), ' ', char(9), char(13), ' ')

DECLARE @TrimPattern nvarchar(max) = '%[^ ' + char(9) + char(13) + char(10) +']%'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Test, PATINDEX(@TrimPattern, @Test), LEN(@Test) - PATINDEX(@TrimPattern, @Test) - PATINDEX(@TrimPattern, LTRIM(REVERSE(@Test))) + 2)

Answer (score -1):

SELECT REPLACE(name, ' ', '') FROM Customer

Comment: But that would remove _all_ spaces from the string, not just from the _ends_. That's not what the original question is asking.