# TRIM RTRIM LTRIM Performance

Tags: string, performance, oracle, trim

I am only required to do `RTRIM()` in some part of query but if i do TRIM() will that affect performance.

Is `Trim()` 
Slower/Faster/Exactly same(NOT even has negligible difference) 
compared to `RTRIM()` AND `LTRIM()`?

This is with respect to Oracle 10g ONLY.

But in case of SQL Server 2005,
Do we have function / method 'x()' such that it can replace `RTRIM(LTRIM(' blah.. blah..  '))` to a single function ?

I simply mean of having "single" function for doing the same functionality what both `RTRIM()` AND `LTRIM()` does.

Comment: SQL Server 2017 has [`TRIM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql). Also, related: [How to trim a string in MS SQL older than SQL Server 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179625/3258851)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on this rough test there is a small difference:

```
DECLARE
n PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
s1 VARCHAR2(32767);
s2 VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
s1 := LPAD('X',15000,' ') || RPAD('X',15000,' ');
FOR i IN 1..1000000 LOOP
  NULL;
END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Baseline: ' || (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - n));
n := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
FOR i IN 1..1000000 LOOP
  s2 := LTRIM(s1);
END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('LTRIM: ' || (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - n));
n := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
FOR i IN 1..1000000 LOOP
  s2 := RTRIM(s1);
END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('RTRIM: ' || (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - n));
n := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
FOR i IN 1..1000000 LOOP
  s2 := TRIM(s1);
END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('TRIM: ' || (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - n));
END;
```

The difference amounts to up to 0.000128 hundredth's of a second in the worst case:

```
Baseline: 0
LTRIM: 113
RTRIM: 103
TRIM: 8
Baseline: 0
LTRIM: 136
RTRIM: 133
TRIM: 8
```

Comment: The difference may be explained by the fact that LTRIM and RTRIM can trim a *set* of characters, whereas TRIM only has to look for a single character.

Comment: Thanks for analysis & explanation.But what in case of TRIM("specific-sequence-of-chars-instead-of-spaces-only").

Comment: Ok, changed `s1 := LPAD('X',32000,'X');` and the performance difference is reduced - less than 0.000091 hundredths of a second.

Comment: What you should take away from this is that there is no practical difference; so you should always use whatever most closely fits what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

The difference in performance will generally be undetectable, especially if it's within a query that gets its data from a table. Choose whichever fits your requirements.

Comment: Irrespective of minor or undetectable diffrence/s in TRIM() and LTRIM()/RTRIM() how does it affect perfomance, even if it is of minimal/unrecognizable magnitude ?

Comment: If the difference is undetectable, that means we cannot say for sure whether one method is faster than the other. That's what "undetectable" means.

Comment: Thanks for a nice example.Still according me TRIM() would be slower than RTRIM() or LTRIM() but as i do not know algorithm used behind them or code inside it,so i was trying to find explanation or contradiction to my belief.

Answer (score 2):

The question is irrelevant for SQL Server, since it implements `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` but not `TRIM`.

See the list of [SQL 2005 string functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen anything like a benchmark on the Trims in SQL Server. I've used it a lot and do find some minor performance when dealing with lots of data...minor performance.

Comment: Irrespective of minor or undetectable diffrence/s in TRIM() and LTRIM()/RTRIM() how does it affect perfomance, even if it is of minimal/unrecognizable magnitude ?