# SQL Server 2012 - remove right spaces in select clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

We changed our database from IBM Informix to SQL Server. Our ERP as default behavior save all data with right spaces filling the column size for `varchar`'s.

Informix didn't return these right spaces, but now with SQL Server, its returning these right spaces for all selects, and it's a big problem.

I tried to use `SET ANSI_PADDING OFF`, but I'm still getting the right spaces.

Does anybody know a solution for my problem?

I would like to remove all right spaces for all varchar columns in all selects.

tks.

Comment: Where are you seeing these spaces?  Are these spaces added in so the columns align or when you export the data to a text file?  If they are in the underlying data, then you should fix the values in the database.

Answer (score 0):

how about using `RTRIM`?

```
SELECT RTRIM(ColumnName)
FROM tableName
```

if you want to update those columns to remove the trailing whitespace,

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = RTRIM(columnName)
```

Comment: If I do that, I´ll have to change all my source codes in all systems we have. I need a way that all selects return data without the right spaces. tks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the RTRIM() function or change your datatypes to varchar() or nvarchar()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried trimming the whitespace in your query, as per below?

[In a SELECT statement(MS SQL) how do you trim a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179625/in-a-select-statementms-sql-how-do-you-trim-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you have all the SQL code in your application and you do not want to go through and change that and push the application out. If you do not want to do that, short of creating some sort of app that hijacks the sql server calls and transforms them you will need to sanitize your data.

Answer (score 0):

If your ERP requires the spaces to remain for it to function correctly, the only solution that I can see is to update all of your select queries to `RTRIM` the data.

This may simply be the price you have to pay to change database systems.