# TRIM function on SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

IN SQLite I wrote :

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYFIELD = TRIM(MYFIELD);
```

What to do to have this on SQL Server 2014 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In a SELECT statement(MS SQL) how do you trim a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179625/in-a-select-statementms-sql-how-do-you-trim-a-string)

Comment: Why did you not take the 10 seconds to google that?

Comment: @juergend I hate to comment on a 5 year old comment but having trouble finding an answer like the original poster I felt the need.  Sometimes even though the answer seems easy to obtain, looking for it and finding it is all about what you search for.  For example, I searched google for `sql server 2014 trim function` and got to this question first.  Looking at the other results on Google my mind was having issues grasping the fact that LTRIM and RTRIM existed when TRIM did not in SQL 2014.  Every time I noticed a page talking about (L|R)TRIM I was quick to dismiss.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYFIELD = LTRIM(RTRIM(MYFIELD));
```

However, field type must be varchar() and not text.
Otherwise you get "Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of rtrim function"

Answer (score 5):

You need functions `LTRIM` (to trim from left) and `RTRIM` (to trim from right):

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYFIELD = LTRIM(RTRIM(MYFIELD));
```

Comment: where do I get this function i.e how do I write it?

Comment: You don't have to write the function, `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` are inbuild functions. Use **dotnetom's** query. It will work. @user3927897

Comment: I get : Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of rtrim function.

Answer (score 1):

you should use LTRIM then RTRIM function like this
UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYFIELD = LTRIM(RTRIM(MYFIELD AS VARCHAR(SIZE))

Answer (score 0):

***If we also want to handle white spaces/unwanted tabs:***

Check and Try the below script (**Unit Tested**)-

```
--Declaring
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE(col_1 VARCHAR(100));

--Test Samples
INSERT INTO @Tbl (col_1)
VALUES
('  EY     y            
Salem')
, ('  EY     P    ort       Chennai   ')
, ('  EY     Old           Park   ')
, ('  EY   ')
, ('  EY   ')
,(''),(null),('d                           
    f');

SELECT col_1 AS INPUT,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(col_1,CHAR(10),' ')
        ,CHAR(11),' ')
        ,CHAR(12),' ')
        ,CHAR(13),' ')
        ,CHAR(14),' ')
        ,CHAR(160),' ')
        ,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),' ')
    ,CHAR(9),' ')
    ,' ',CHAR(17)+CHAR(18))
    ,CHAR(18)+CHAR(17),'')
    ,CHAR(17)+CHAR(18),' ')
    )) AS [OUTPUT]
FROM @Tbl;
```