# remove spaces from a table column in sql

Tags: sql

Guys I need to remove the spaces from following column using a select statement.
I want to use this as primary key for the table .
when i use LTRIM or RTRIM its not working give the same out as its in table column.

[coupon_No]

001 3251254612 1

001 3251254612 2

001 3251254612 3

001 3251254612 4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trim a string in MS SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179625/how-to-trim-a-string-in-ms-sql)

Comment: Well, good luck with that. Otherwise, what have you tried or considered?

Comment: Unless you're really looking for a generic standard SQL solution that works on all major engines, you should really tag whether your DBMS is Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL, Access...

Answer (score 0):

Try [**REPLACE()**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) function:

```
SELECT REPLACE([coupon_No], ' ', '') FROM <your_table>;
```

Answer (score 0):

replace(column_name, ' ', '')
 //Remove white space

column_name=replace(column_name, '\t', '')
 //Remove all tab